# ASP.NET Core Integration Testing & Mocking using Moq

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, moq, xunit, asp.net-core-testhost

I have the following [ASP.NET Core integration test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2) using a custom `WebApplicationFactory`

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint>
    where TEntryPoint : class
{
    public CustomWebApplicationFactory()
    {
        this.ClientOptions.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        this.ClientOptions.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost");
    }

    public ApplicationOptions ApplicationOptions { get; private set; }

    public Mock<IClockService> ClockServiceMock { get; private set; }

    public void VerifyAllMocks() => Mock.VerifyAll(this.ClockServiceMock);

    protected override TestServer CreateServer(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        this.ClockServiceMock = new Mock<IClockService>(MockBehavior.Strict);

        builder
            .UseEnvironment("Testing")
            .ConfigureTestServices(
                services =>
                {
                    services.AddSingleton(this.ClockServiceMock.Object);
                });

        var testServer = base.CreateServer(builder);

        using (var serviceScope = testServer.Host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var serviceProvider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
            this.ApplicationOptions = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ApplicationOptions>>().Value;
        }

        return testServer;
    }
}
```

which looks like it should work but the problem is that the `ConfigureTestServices` method is never being called, so my mock is never registered with the IoC container. You can find the full source code [here](https://github.com/Dotnet-Boxed/Templates/tree/cursor-paging-in-api-template/Source/ApiTemplate).

```cs
public class FooControllerTest : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpClient client;
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory;
    private readonly Mock<IClockService> clockServiceMock;

    public FooControllerTest(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.client = factory.CreateClient();
        this.clockServiceMock = this.factory.ClockServiceMock;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Delete_FooFound_Returns204NoContent()
    {
        this.clockServiceMock.SetupGet(x => x.UtcNow).ReturnsAsync(new DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);

        var response = await this.client.DeleteAsync("/foo/1");

        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, response.StatusCode);
    }

    public void Dispose() => this.factory.VerifyAllMocks();
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've blogged about [ASP.NET Core Integration Testing & Mocking using Moq](https://rehansaeed.com/asp-net-core-integration-testing-mocking-using-moq/). It's not simple and requires some setup but I hope it helps someone out. Here is the basic code you need using ASP.NET Core 3.1:

## Startup

The `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods in your applications `Startup` class must be virtual. This is so that we can iherit from this class in our tests and replace production versions of certain services with mock versions.

```cs
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly IWebHostingEnvironment webHostingEnvironment;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostingEnvironment webHostingEnvironment)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.webHostingEnvironment = webHostingEnvironment;
    }

    public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) =>
        ...

    public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application) =>
        ...
}
```

## TestStartup

In your test project, override the Startup class with one that registers the mock and the mock object with IoC.

```cs
public class TestStartup : Startup
{
    private readonly Mock<IClockService> clockServiceMock;

    public TestStartup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        : base(configuration, hostingEnvironment)
    {
        this.clockServiceMock = new Mock<IClockService>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    }
 
    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddSingleton(this.clockServiceMock);

        base.ConfigureServices(services);

        services
            .AddSingleton(this.clockServiceMock.Object);
    }
}
```

## CustomWebApplicationFactory

In your test project, write a custom `WebApplicationFactory` that configures the `HttpClient` and resolves the mocks from the `TestStartup`, then exposes them as properties, ready for our integration test to consume them. Note that I'm also changing the environment to `Testing` and telling it to use the `TestStartup` class for startup.

Note also that I've implemented `IDisposable`'s `Dispose method to verify all of my strict mocks. This means I don't need to verify any mocks manually myself. Verification of all mock setups happens automatically when xUnit is disposing the test class.

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint>
    where TEntryPoint : class
{
    public CustomWebApplicationFactory()
    {
        this.ClientOptions.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        this.ClientOptions.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost");
    }

    public ApplicationOptions ApplicationOptions { get; private set; }

    public Mock<IClockService> ClockServiceMock { get; private set; }

    public void VerifyAllMocks() => Mock.VerifyAll(this.ClockServiceMock);

    protected override void ConfigureClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = this.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var serviceProvider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
            this.ApplicationOptions = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ApplicationOptions>>().Value;
            this.ClockServiceMock = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Mock<IClockService>>();
        }

        base.ConfigureClient(client);
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder) =>
        builder
            .UseEnvironment("Testing")
            .UseStartup<TestStartup>();

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.VerifyAllMocks();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

## Integration Tests

I'm using xUnit to write my tests. Note that the generic type passed to `CustomWebApplicationFactory` is `Startup` and not `TestStartup`. This generic type is used to find the location of your application project on disk and not to start the application.

I setup a mock in my test and I've implemented `IDisposable` to verify all mocks for all my tests at the end but you can do this step in the test method itself if you like.

Note also, that I'm not using xUnit's `IClassFixture` to only boot up the application once as the ASP.NET Core documentation tells you to do. If I did so, I'd have to reset the mocks between each test and also you would only be able to run the integration tests serially one at a time. With the method below, each test is fully isolated and they can be run in parallel. This uses up more CPU and each test takes longer to execute but I think it's worth it.

```cs
public class FooControllerTest : CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    private readonly HttpClient client;
    private readonly Mock<IClockService> clockServiceMock;

    public FooControllerTest()
    {
        this.client = this.CreateClient();
        this.clockServiceMock = this.ClockServiceMock;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetFoo_Default_Returns200OK()
    {
        this.clockServiceMock.Setup(x => x.UtcNow).ReturnsAsync(new DateTimeOffset(2000, 1, 1));

        var response = await this.client.GetAsync("/foo");

        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

## xunit.runner.json

I'm using xUnit. We need to turn off shadown copying, so any separate files like `appsettings.json` are placed in the right place beside the application DLL file. This ensures that our application running in an integration test can still read the `appsettings.json` file.

```json
{
  "shadowCopy": false
}
```

## appsettings.Testing.json

Should you have configuration that you want to change just for your integration tests, you can add a `appsettings.Testing.json` file into your application. This configuration file will only be read in our integration tests because we set the environment name to 'Testing'.

Comment: If i want to use In Memory DB, then how can I do so? Somehow in 3.1 my in memory DB never gets used and only the DB that was registered in the app Startup gets used. I found a link into github issue here(https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13918#issuecomment-532162945) , but could not figure out how to override this behavior.

Comment: You said "I'm not using xUnit's IClassFixture to only boot up the application once as the ASP.NET Core documentation tells you to do. If I did so, I'd have to reset the mocks between each test and also you would only be able to run the integration tests serially one at a time." I understand IClassFixture is to share stuff... but the thing being shared is a factory and should not have state, so it is safe to run in parallel? Apparently not since I seem to be getting race condition bugs... care to explain how a shared factory has state that could break tests?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to handle this is to factor out parts of your `Startup` that will need to be substituted during test. For example, instead of calling `services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(...);` directly in `ConfigureServices`, create a virtual private method like:

```cs
protected virtual void ConfigureDatabase(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(...);
}
```

Then, in your test project, create a class like `TestStartup` which derives from your SUT's `Startup` class. Then, you can override these virtual methods to sub in your test services, mocks, etc.

Finally, just do something like:

```cs
builder
    .UseEnvironment("Testing")
    .UseStartup<TestStartup>();
```

Comment: Is "private virtual" possible in c#?

Comment: Good catch. Crazy I and no one else noticed that until now. I meant protected.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a fake startup:

```cs
public class FakeStartup : Startup
{
    public FakeStartup(IConfiguration configuration)
        : base(configuration)
    {
    }

    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        base.ConfigureServices(services);

        // Your fake go here
        //services.AddScoped<IService, FakeService>();
    }
}
```

Then use it with `IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<FakeStartup>>`.

Make sure to make your original `ConfigureServices` method virtual.

Comment: The generic type param to `WebApplicationFactory` is `TEntryPoint`. It is used to determine the assembly of the SUT, *not* the `Startup` class to use. As such, it should remain `Startup` here.